# Quick translation of JS if/else shorthand?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How this carousel works would become a little bit more understandable if I could see these if/else statement written the long way. From what I understand, if/else shorthand goes:

`isThisTrue? thenDoThis: ifNotDoThis`

But I get a bit confused when more conditionals get added. Any help would be much appreciated.

`n.attr("id")=="right"?currentIndex==$("#slider li").size()-1?currentIndex=0:currentIndex++:n.attr("id")=="left"?currentIndex==0?currentIndex=$("#slider li").size()-1:currentIndex--:currentIndex=n.attr("data-position");`

`SetTheme:function(n){n.hasClass("dark")?($("#logo").addClass("dark"),$("#ips").addClass("dark"),$("#nav").addClass("dark"), $("#but-links").addClass("dark"),$("#but-search").addClass("dark")):n.hasClass("light")&&($("#logo").removeClass("dark"),$("#ips").removeClass("dark"), $("#nav").removeClass("dark"), $("#but-links").removeClass("dark"), $("#but-search").removeClass("dark"))}`

Comment: this is horrendous code..  more complicated to read definitely doesnt mean better programming.  look for question marks, and colons to identify the if and else blocks.

Comment: Looks like minified code.  At least I hope someone did not intentionally write that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whatever you do, don't write code like that, and if you find code written like that, fix it.  You're confused by it because it's confusing. It's not you. :-)

But the rule is that the operands to the conditional operator are *greedy*, left-to-right. Let's remind ourselves of the three operands to the conditional operator (as you did in your question):

```
operand1 ? operand2 : operand3
```

So since the operands are greedy, that means, for instance:

```
val = true  ? true ? "a" : "b" : "c"; // is "a"
val = false ? true ? "a" : "b" : "c"; // is "c"
//          ^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//          | \              /
//          |  \            /
//          |   +----------+--- this is operand2 to...
//          +------------------ this conditional operator
```

...because they're equivalent to

```
val = true  ? (true ? "a" : "b") : ("c"); // is "a"
val = false ? (true ? "a" : "b") : ("c"); // is "c"
```

Comment: That makes this clear, thank you. If I could ask one more thing: If `n.hasClass("dark")?` then it will add the class name .dark to a bunch of things, but if `n.hasClass("light")` then it makes use of the && operator and removes the dark class from a bunch of things. Couldn't the programmer have replaced the && with a ? and achieved the same result?

Comment: @user2658433: They could have achieved a similar result, if they'd replaced `&&` with `?` **and** added a `:` with something in it that didn't do anything. `x && y();` is another obscure JavaScript idiom which (in my view) should be avoided in nearly all cases. What it does is basically `x ? y() : /*...do nothing...*/;` *(Please, please tell me that this is minified/compiled code, and not something someone actually wrote. It's a serious abuse of the conditional and comma operators.)*

Comment: Before I pressed enter a bunch of times to make this readable in a different file, this was a javascript file that looked minified/compressed. How does this file abuse the conditional and comma operators? (Is it overuse or abuse?)

Comment: @user2658433: If it's minified, it's fine. But if it were code that humans were supposed to read, it's horrible. :-)